# Testing of post method in rest api

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

Flask, sqlalchemy, mysql

I have my database with production data.

How can I test post request via unit tests (with no changes in production base)?

Do I need to copy my base? How can I do it?

Comment: Use an in-memory data structure like a Map of objects instead of an actual database. Hopefully your data access is separate from controllers.

Comment: just make `dump` of production db. `import dump` into local mysql. run application and debug anything.